# How to iterate through a Map[B,Int] in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a Map[B,Int] that I am trying to iterate over:
So I do something like:

map foreach { case (k,v) => println(k + " " + v)}

However I keep getting the error that there is a type mismatch:
Found: Unit
Expected: B

I have read several times on different tutorials that traversing a map is always the same regardless of what type is point to another.

I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Can you post a [complete] minimal test-case? I ask this because `Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2) foreach {case (k,v) => println(k + " " + v)}` works as expected.

Comment: If `map` is not a reference to a `Map[B, Int]` but rather is the map method of the class you are inside of then this might happen, `foreach` returns Unit which might not be what `map` wants.

Comment: I'm sorry, by map i just mean variable name. val map = scala.collection.immutable.Map[B,Int]().

Comment: What is B? Your problem probably lies there. It works fine if B is a String or any other simple class.

Comment: B is supposed to be an arbitrary type. So when a person creates an object of a class that may look like MyClass[B](m: Map[B,Int]) ..., it would look like val myMap = new MyClass[String](Map("Hello" -> 2))..

Comment: Please edit your question and add MyClass and the code where you use map foreach. Also take a look at the comment above made by winged submariner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the toString method, otherwise print won't work.
This is done by default for Int or String so that's why it complains only for B class.